# Why does my iframe embed have text overlaying this image?

Tags: html, web, iframe, overlay

I'm trying to embed an advertisement and the text from the advertisement is overlaying other text. How do I fix that?
Sorry, I've never coded much before.

'''

```
        <p style = "padding-left: 180px;">

        <iframe 
                style="width:120px; height: 240px;" 
                src = "//ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&amp;OneJS=1&amp;Operation=GetAdHtml&amp;MarketPlace=US&amp;source=ac&amp;ref=tf_til&amp;ad_type=product_link&amp;tracking_id=mindbodyali09-20&amp;marketplace=amazon&amp;region=US&amp;placement=B000Z94WAK&amp;asins=B000Z94WAK&amp;linkId=5ec29be62e53e9cf5a2bf8df02de35e5&amp;show_border=false&amp;link_opens_in_new_window=true&amp;price_color=333333&amp;title_color=0066c0&amp;bg_color=ffffff" 
                frameborder="0" 
                marginwidth = "0" 
                marginheight="0" 
                scrolling = "no">
            </iframe>

        </p>

    </div>'''
```

[image]

Comment: Please post the full code

Comment: Would tell IFrame is too small so that its content has broken layout.